# ArcObjects - Adding ArcGIS Server Layer to MXD Programtically

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I am trying to add a layer from ArcGIS online to a mxd programatically with no luck.  See code sample below.  The error is happening at pAGSServerConnectionFactory.Open(props, 0);

Anyone been able to do this?

```
private void AddArcGISOnlineLayer(IMap map)
        {
            IAGSServerConnectionName servConnName = new AGSServerConnectionNameClass();
            IPropertySet props = new PropertySetClass();
            props.SetProperty("URL", "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
            servConnName.ConnectionProperties = props;
            IAGSServerConnectionFactory pAGSServerConnectionFactory = new AGSServerConnectionFactoryClass();
            IAGSServerConnection pAGSConnection = pAGSServerConnectionFactory.Open(props, 0);
            IAGSEnumServerObjectName pEnumSOName = pAGSConnection.ServerObjectNames;
            IAGSServerObjectName pSOName = pEnumSOName.Next();

            while (pSOName != null)
            {
                if (pSOName.Name == "Layers")
                    break;
                pSOName = pEnumSOName.Next();
            }

            IName pName = (IName)pSOName;
            IMapServer mapServer = (IMapServer)pName.Open();
            IMapServerLayer msLyr = new MapServerLayerClass();
            msLyr.ServerConnect(pSOName, mapServer.DefaultMapName);
            IMapServerGroupLayer group = (IMapServerGroupLayer)msLyr;
            ILayer msLayer = (ILayer)msLyr;
            map.AddLayer(msLayer);

        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code below works for me with 10.0 sp2 in an arcmap add-in.  Adapted from [Thad Tilton's code](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=279173#863864).

```
protected override void OnClick()
{
    try
    {
        string url =
        "http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer";

        var visIndicies = new List<int>();
        visIndicies.Add(2); // just make the counties visible
        var layer = GetArcGISMapServiceLayer("States", visIndicies, url,50, false);
        if (layer != null)
            ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.AddLayer(layer);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (ex != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(ex.Message);
            sb.AppendLine(ex.StackTrace);
            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
    }
}


public static ILayer GetArcGISMapServiceLayer(string name, List<int> visibleIndices, string url,
        short transparency, bool isTiled)
{
    ILayer outLayer = null;
    string svcName = GetServiceName(url);
    string svcUrl = GetServiceUrl(url);
    var gisServer = OpenConnection(svcUrl);

    var soName = FindServerObjectname(gisServer, svcName);
    if (soName == null)
        throw new Exception("unable to find serverobject for " + svcName);

    outLayer = GetArcGisServerGroupLayer(soName) as ILayer;
    if (outLayer != null)
    {
        if (!isTiled)
        {
            var grpLayer = outLayer as ICompositeLayer;
            for (int i = 0; i < grpLayer.Count; i++)
            {
                Debug.Print("Setting visibility for " + grpLayer.get_Layer(i).Name);
                SetVisibility(grpLayer.get_Layer(i), visibleIndices);
            }
        }
        Debug.Print("setting {0} transparency to {1}", name, transparency);
        ((ILayerEffects)outLayer).Transparency = transparency;
        outLayer.Name = name;
    }
    return outLayer;
}

private static IMapServerLayer GetArcGisServerGroupLayer(IAGSServerObjectName3 soName)
{
    IMapServerLayer outLayer = null;
    var factory = new MapServerLayerFactory() as ILayerFactory;
    try
    {
        //create an enum of layers using the name object (will contain only a single layer)
        outLayer = factory.Create(soName).Next() as IMapServerLayer;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(factory);
    }
    return outLayer;
}

private static IAGSServerObjectName3 FindServerObjectname(IAGSServerConnection gisServer, string svcName)
{
    var soNames = gisServer.ServerObjectNames;
    IAGSServerObjectName3 soName;
    while ((soName = (IAGSServerObjectName3)soNames.Next()) != null)
    {
        Debug.Print("soName: " + soName.Name);
        if ((soName.Type == "MapServer") && (soName.Name.ToUpper() == svcName.ToUpper()))
        {
            return soName;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static IAGSServerConnection OpenConnection(string svcUrl)
{            
    //create a property set to hold connection properties
    var connectionProps = new PropertySet() as IPropertySet;
    //specify the URL for the server
    connectionProps.SetProperty("URL", svcUrl); // layerDefinition.Url);
    //define username and password for the connection
    //connectionProps.SetProperty("USER", "<USER>");
    //connectionProps.SetProperty("PASSWORD", "<PASS>");
    //open the server connection, pass in the property set, get a connection object back

    //create a new ArcGIS Server connection factory
    var connectionFactory = (IAGSServerConnectionFactory2)new AGSServerConnectionFactory();
    var gisServer = connectionFactory.Open(connectionProps, 0);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(connectionFactory);
    return gisServer;
}

private static void SetVisibility(ILayer lyr, List<int> visibleIds)
{
    // recurse and set visibility
    IMapServerSublayer subLayer = lyr as IMapServerSublayer;
    if (subLayer == null)
        return;
    int id = subLayer.LayerDescription.ID;

    if (visibleIds.Contains(id))
        lyr.Visible = true;
    else
        lyr.Visible = false;
    IMapServerGroupLayer gLayer = lyr as IMapServerGroupLayer;
    if (gLayer != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gLayer.Count; i++)
            SetVisibility(gLayer.get_Layer(i), visibleIds);
    }
}

private static string GetServiceUrl(string url)
{
    // remove the "rest" part of the url 
    int idx = url.ToString().ToUpper().IndexOf(@"/REST/");
    string svcUrl = url.Substring(0, idx) + @"/services";
    return svcUrl;
}

private static string GetServiceName(string url)
{
    int idx = url.ToString().ToUpper().IndexOf(@"/SERVICES/") + 10;
    string svcName = url.ToString().Substring(idx).Trim();
    if (svcName.ToUpper().EndsWith(@"/MAPSERVER"))
    {
        svcName = svcName.Substring(0, svcName.ToUpper().LastIndexOf(@"/MAPSERVER"));
    }
    return svcName;
}
```