# How to consume an ArcGIS Server service from ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, c#

I have this end point to my ArcGIS Server: 
http://myarcgisserver/arcgis/rest/services/prueba/GMRE/MapServer

I'm trying it with GisClient:

```
public void requestServer(string username, string password)
    {

        string url = "http://myarcgisserver/arcgis/rest/services/prueba/GMRE/MapServer";
        var gisServer = OpenConnection(url);
        MessageBox.Show(gisServer.ToString());

    }


private static IAGSServerConnection OpenConnection(string svcUrl)
    {
        //create a property set to hold connection properties
        var connectionProps = new PropertySet() as IPropertySet;
        //specify the URL for the server
        connectionProps.SetProperty("URL", svcUrl);

        //create a new ArcGIS Server connection factory
        var connectionFactory = (IAGSServerConnectionFactory2)new AGSServerConnectionFactory();
        var gisServer = connectionFactory.Open(connectionProps, 0);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(connectionFactory);
        return gisServer;
    }
```

But I get a exception saying 'Invalid url'

My service in the browser:

[image]

How can I consume it from arcobjects?

Comment: see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/14865/59

Answer (score 1):

Often, when constructing ArcGIS Server service URLs you need to include the type of service you're connecting to in the URL, such as `MapServer` for a standard map service.

Try changing your URL to something like `"http://myarcgisserver/arcgis/rest/services/prueba/MapServer"`

See [Components of ArcGIS URLs - ArcGIS Server end user URLs](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/linux/components-of-arcgis-urls.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_41D52658B83E43CBBE34C15D1015F0D0), specifically the section labelled "ArcGIS services", and see the table "REST service values" if `MapServer` is not correct for your URL.

Comment: I added the type service 'MapServer', but I still getting the exception with invalid url message

Comment: @Manso If you go to that URL in your browser, does it open it?

Comment: Yes, I added a picture

Comment: @Manso Note that the URL in your browser is different than the one in your question.  You are missing `GMRE` in  your question.

Comment: I gonna correct it for the url that now I'm trying

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but here's how I have queried an ArcGIS Server Feature Service in the past:

```
//query objectid = 1
string url = @"https://my.arcgis.server/arcgis/rest/services/MyProject/MapServer/0/query?where=OBJECTID=1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=pjson";
string json;

using (WebClient w = new WebClient())
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(w.OpenRead(queryUrl));
    json = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
```

where `json` is a JSON string you can deserialize to an object.